# ConTeXt urls in main font

Tags: context, pandoc

I have a URL like this: `\useURL[url1][https://example.com]\from[url1]`

(This is output from [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).)

I would like it to be in the main font for the document, not a mono font. With LaTeX and hyperref.sty, I would add `\urlstyle{same}`. Is there an equivalent to this for ConTeXt?

This is an MWE, which is the output from Pandoc:

```
% Enable hyperlinks
\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
  style=,
  color=,
  contrastcolor=]

% make chapter, section bookmarks visible when opening document
\placebookmarks[chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, subsubsubsection, subsubsubsubsection][chapter, section]
\setupinteractionscreen[option={bookmark,title}]

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,middle}]
\setupbackend[export=yes]
\setupstructure[state=start,method=auto]

% use microtypography
\definefontfeature[default][default][script=latn, protrusion=quality, expansion=quality, itlc=yes, textitalics=yes, onum=yes, pnum=yes]
\definefontfeature[default:tnum][default][tnum=yes, pnum=no]
\definefontfeature[smallcaps][script=latn, protrusion=quality, expansion=quality, smcp=yes, onum=yes, pnum=yes]
\setupalign[hz,hanging]
\setupitaliccorrection[global, always]

\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic] % use italic as em, not slanted

\definefallbackfamily[mainface][rm][CMU Serif][preset=range:greek, force=yes]
\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][Latin Modern Roman]
\definefontfamily[mainface][mm][Latin Modern Math]
\definefontfamily[mainface][ss][Latin Modern Sans]
\definefontfamily[mainface][tt][Latin Modern Typewriter][features=none]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\setuphead[chapter]            [style=\tfd\setupinterlinespace,header=empty]
\setuphead[section]            [style=\tfc\setupinterlinespace]
\setuphead[subsection]         [style=\tfb\setupinterlinespace]
\setuphead[subsubsection]      [style=\bf]
\setuphead[subsubsubsection]   [style=\sc]
\setuphead[subsubsubsubsection][style=\it]

\setuphead[chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, subsubsubsection, subsubsubsubsection][number=no]

\definedescription
  [description]
  [headstyle=bold, style=normal, location=hanging, width=broad, margin=1cm, alternative=hanging]

\setupitemize[autointro]    % prevent orphan list intro
\setupitemize[indentnext=no]

\defineitemgroup[enumerate]
\setupenumerate[each][fit][itemalign=left,distance=.5em,style={\feature[+][default:tnum]}]

\setupfloat[figure][default={here,nonumber}]
\setupfloat[table][default={here,nonumber}]

\setupxtable[frame=off]
\setupxtable[head][topframe=on,bottomframe=on]
\setupxtable[body][]
\setupxtable[foot][bottomframe=on]


\starttext

\useURL[url1][https://example.com]\from[url1]

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you look for `\setupurl`.

```
\starttext
Text \useURL[url1][https://example.com]\from[url1]

\setupurl
  [style=]

Text \useURL[url1][https://example.com]\from[url1]

\stoptext
```

[image: urls in different styles]

Comment: Do you happen to know why `\setupinteraction[state=start, style=normal, color=, contrastcolor=]` doesn't work?

Comment: I have only tried `\setupinteraction`for interactive internal links in the document, like links to sections, equations, figures and so on.